# Aspects not working in spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I am creating a Spring boot application with Aspects, but it is not working. It is not getting picked up.

I have defined EnableAspectJAutoProxy in a custom configuration class.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class AppConfig {

@Bean
public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
    return new ModelMapper();
}
```

Going through multiple solutions on stack overflow, I found that adding @Component might solve my issue but when I add @Component, my application fails to start.

please find the error below-

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'projectingArgumentResolverBeanPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/web/config/ProjectingArgumentResolverRegistrar.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:277) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:805) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at com.dimensions.inc.personalTrackerbank.PersonalTrackerbankApplication.main(PersonalTrackerbankApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': warning no match for this type name: com.dimensions.inc.personalTrackerbank.bankInfoInterface [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:607) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:409) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1165) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:91) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:111) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:92) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:280) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1130) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: com.dimensions.inc.personalTrackerbank.bankInfoInterface [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:319) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.21.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:223) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.obtainPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:194) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:173) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:233) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:295) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:327) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:128) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:78) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:366) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:318) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:438) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1789) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
```

My code -

resource file -

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/data")
public class PtbBankResource {

     @GetMapping("/ret")
     @ValidateUser(headerName = "Authorization")
     public ResponseEntity<?> getCall()
     {
          return ResponseEntity.ok().body("data Successfull");
     }
}
```

custom annotation -

```
@Component
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface ValidateUser {    
    String headerName() default "";
}
```

Aspect class -

```java
@Aspect
public class AuthAspect {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthAspect.class);

@Autowired
PtbUtils ptbUtils;

@Around(value = "execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(ValidateUser)")
public Object authValidation(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, ValidateUser validateUser) throws Throwable
{
    logger.info("Inside authValidation class");

    String headerName = validateUser.headerName().isEmpty() ? HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION : validateUser.headerName();
    HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();

    logger.info("headerName = " + headerName);
    logger.info("request = " + request);
    String token = request.getHeader(headerName);
    logger.info("token = " + token);
    Boolean value = ptbUtils.validateJwtToken(token);
    System.out.println("value = " + value);
    return joinPoint.proceed();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the replies and reading the official documentation extensively, I found that the @annotation value requires the custom annotation's object rather than class.

Ref - https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-around-advice  (Heading 6.2.4)

so my Aspect class becomes ->

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class AuthAspect {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthAspect.class);

@Autowired
PtbUtils ptbUtils;

@Around("@annotation(validateUser)")
public Object authValidation(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, ValidateUser validateUser) throws Throwable
{
    logger.info("Inside authValidation class");

    String headerName = validateUser.headerName().isEmpty() ? HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION : validateUser.headerName();
    HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();

    logger.info("headerName = " + headerName);
    logger.info("request = " + request);
    String token = request.getHeader(headerName);
    logger.info("token = " + token);
    Boolean value = ptbUtils.validateJwtToken(token);
    System.out.println("value = " + value);
    return joinPoint.proceed();
}
}
```

Edit -

The fix initial issue as highlighted in my question, it required removing the @Component tag from @interface.

After removing @Component from @interface and then adding it to the Aspect class, it gave a new error -

```
error at::0 formal unbound in pointcut
```

To fix that, the solution provided before "Edit" worked.

Comment: Your answer is not fully correct and does not solve the original problem with the error in the question: Of course, something like `@annotation(my.package.MyAnnotation)` is also possible, if you do not need a reference to the annotation. In your case, you do need one, and there it is correct to use the bound method parameter name instead of the fully qualified class name. But before fixing that, your error message would have been `error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut`, not the error in your question. You also forgot `@Component` in your aspect in the question, correcting it here.

Comment: Thank you for highlighting. Yes, there are a few more updates as suggested by @michiel.
Updating the same in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `@Component` annotation from your `@interface` class and add it to the `@Aspect` class. Then, modify your @Around annotation to: `@Around(value="@annotation(fully.qualified.package.here.ValidateUser)")`.

By the way, instead of creating a custom aspect to authenticate and authorize a user I strongly suggest to use the Spring Security module instead, and put your custom auth logic in a custom PermissionEvaluator. Or, given you mention OAuth in your snippet, verify whether a Spring security OAuth2 setup will suffice.

More info on https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-create-new-custom-security-expression and https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth

Comment: I did the steps mentioned above of moving @Component from the interface to the Aspect class but still got the same error while starting the application.

I am using the spring-boot version 3.2.3 (if it helps.)

I am developing this project to brush up on my understanding of spring AOPs and there could be nothing better than implementing a token fetching from headers and validating its authenticity.

Comment: I've updated my answer regarding the @Around annotation

Comment: Removing `execution(* (..))` has no effect on Spring AOP aspects, it would only change behaviour in native Aspectj aspects, but widening the range, not narrowing it as you seem to think. In Spring AOP, all advices are implicitly of `execution` type. Making the `execution` part explicit is IMO even a good practice, because it could always be that in the future you swith from simple Spring AOP to full-fledged AspectJ.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your pointcut is too broad, targeting too many classes. Spring AOP can check `@annotation` only during runtime, which means that it needs to check all classes including internal Spring and third-party components, which can lead to hen vs. egg problems during component initialisation and wiring. Simply limit the pointcut scope by:

```java
... && within(my.app.base_package..*)
```

In native AspectJ, this would not be a problem.

P.S.: I am not an active Spring user, but AFAIK Spring has its own validation framework. You can, of course, use AOP as a perfectly valid (no pun intended) use case, but chances are that the built-in stuff is good enough for you.

Comment: Spring has a Hibernate validator as its validation framework but it works with POJOs. I have added the solution.